# How to convert Image from Url to base64 in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, firebase-storage

I am getting Url of images from firebase storage and want to convert these images to base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side js. With FileReader and fetch.

```js
const base64 = await fetch('https://i.imgur.com/gBi0yjr.png')
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return new Promise((res) => {
      reader.onloadend = () => {
      res(reader.result);
    }})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a go:

```
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });

request.get(/* URL FIREBASE */, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        data = Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```